# Linq to sql - executing mulitple queries on the same transaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, concurrency

I am creating entries in a contract table using linq to sql.

One column needs to conditionally be assigned an application number from a range of values.

I'd like to simply increment the max existing value, however it is a multi-user application and I'm concerned about multiple contracts receiving the same app number if they happen too close together.

Is there a way to either force the entire thing to use the same transaction, or to execute both during the same submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the code in a `TransactionScope`:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{

     // Perform the changes


     transaction.Complete();
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx for more information about the `TransactionScope` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `SqlConnection` and `SqlTransaction` and supply it to the LINQ to SQL `DataContext`:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var db = new YourDataContext(con))
        {
            // This line is needed in .NET 3.5 (not in 4.0)
            db.Transaction = tran;

            // Do your stuff

            db.SubmitChanges();

            // Do more stuff

            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stored procedure in which you take care of all of the actions that you need in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but when you call submit changes it wraps all the changes in a single transaction - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx

Comment: The problem is that I needed to set a unique value on the object to be inserted based on a scalar query which would have executed immediately. I needed the transaction to extend outside of the submit so this would happen atomically.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you do need to wrap the whole thing in a transaction scope (this will create an sqltransaction under the covers) as in Pieter's answer.